# Firefox/Chrome difference - Redefining the "Worker" constructor

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-worker

Consider this...

```
trueWorker = Worker;
Worker = function(src){
             return new trueWorker(src);
         }
myWorker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(
                       new Blob(["'use strict;'"],{type:'text/javascript'})
                      ));
```

In Chrome this works fine: `myWorker` is a proper Worker. This is useful because it means you can intercept the call to the native constructor, and still return a Worker (or a worker-like interface with a `trueWorker` behind the scenes).

However in Firefox `myWorker` is some kind of dud object with no properties.

What's going on?  Which browser is right? And is there any way to make Firefox do as I want?